# Contador de caracteres event.target.value no useCallback não atualiza para zero

Tags: react, typescript

Estou criando um contador de caracteres que precisa atualizar conforme a quantidade de caracteres digitada no campo de texto. O resultado da função deve ser uma mensagem que especifica a quantidade de caracteres que ainda falta para o usuário atingir o mínimo necessário para enviar a mensagem. Quando o contador está em zero a mensagem diz que faltam 100 caracteres.

O problema aqui é que não sei o motivo de quando eu esvazio o campo de texto ele não atualiza e depois conta o 1 como sendo zero e o 2 como sendo 1 e o 101 como sendo o 100.

Eu preciso que quando não tiverem caracteres digitados no input a mensagem seja o primeiro if onde a mensagem diz que o mínimo de caracteres para que a mensagem seja enviada são 100.

```js
const handleTextCharactersCount = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setCharactersCount(event.target.value.length)

      if (charactersCount === 0) {
        setHelperMessage('Descreva o conteúdo do vídeo. Mínimo 100 Caracteres')
      }

      if (charactersCount > 0) {
        setHelperMessage(
          `Falatam ${
            100 - charactersCount
          } para que você possa enviar a mensagem`,
        )
      }

      if (charactersCount > 100) {
        setHelperMessage('Mínimo de caracateres para envio atingido.')
      }
    },
    [charactersCount],
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema decorre de como o React atualiza o `state` após você invocar uma função `setStateAction`.

Por motivos de otimização, o React não atualiza o `state` de imediato após a função ser invocada, ao invés disso ele empurra esse novo valor (ou `callback`) para uma fila, para que o `state` seja atualizado eventualmente; dessa forma o React pode por exemplo re-renderizar o `DOM` apenas uma vez caso haja a tentativa de mutar o `state` múltiplas vezes em questão de milissegundos.

Então ao invocar `setCharactersCount(event.target.value.length)`, e de imediato checar o valor de `charactersCount` em seguida, ele resultará no mesmo valor que possuía antes de invocar o `setCharactersCount`, pois o React ainda não atualizou o seu `state`.

Para casos como esses, você deveria comparar o valor de `event.target.value.length` mesmo com o tamanho mínimo necessário.

Veja um [exemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-panini-8dnkm?file=/src/App.tsx) funcionando no CodeSandbox com o código abaixo:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [charactersCount, setCharactersCount] = useState(0);
  const [helperMessage, setHelperMessage] = useState(
    "Descreva o conteúdo do vídeo. Mínimo 100 Caracteres"
  );

  const handleTextCharactersCount = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const len = event.target.value.length;
      setCharactersCount(len);

      if (len === 0) {
        setHelperMessage("Descreva o conteúdo do vídeo. Mínimo 100 Caracteres");
      }

      if (len > 0) {
        setHelperMessage(
          `Faltam ${100 - len} para que você possa enviar a mensagem`
        );
      }

      if (len >= 100) {
        setHelperMessage("Mínimo de caracteres para envio atingido.");
      }
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleTextCharactersCount} />
      <div>{helperMessage}</div>
      <div>Caracteres digiados: {charactersCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Então o contador de caracteres nem seria necessário e sim uma constante dentro do próprio callback. Obrigado pela ajuda.